# Digital brewery controller: What buck/boost configuration to get to 240VAC from 208VAC?

Tags: electrical

First of all, I live in the United States.

I own a [240VAC digital control panel](http://www.bru-gear.com/Direct-Fire-Gas-Control-Panel-NG-or-Propane_p_53.html?AffId=1) and am considering leasing a warehouse space that only has 208VAC. The control panel contains a digital computer, and drives a 5.5kW heating element along with a couple of small centrifugal pumps.

The control panel will remain plugged in, but the driven loads will cycle on and off, under software control.

So I know what I'm talking about when I speak to an electrician, I'd appreciate some opinions on the ideal number of transformers, along with configuration and ratings.

The landlord gave me a build-out quote of $8,900 for transformers, a 240V outlet, and four 120V outlets. I think that's high.

I'd appreciate some education.

Comment: That may actually work just fine with 208 volts. I would ask the manufacturer as that could save you a lot of headache.

Comment: I'd be looking long and hard for a different space to lease with extant 240V service - not like it's uncommon or anything. This might be a good read for you?  http://www.schneider-electric.us/sites/us/en/support/faq/faq_main.page?page=content&country=US&lang=en&id=FA91925&locale=en_US&redirect=true

Comment: Thanks, that's good advice. I've read similar links on buck/boosts. Just looking for real-world data.

Comment: What is the distance of the panel to X former to control panel and for the 4 120V outlets.

Comment: @WarLoki Let's say panel-xformer is 5ft, to control panel is another 10ft. 120V outlets at distances of 5ft, 15ft, 25ft and 30ft.

Answer (score 1):

With the Direct Fire Gas Control Panel that you have, the Specifications on the web site state 30a, 240v electric, single phase (**for safety, please use GFCI protection**) so you need to make sure that that GFCI is added to your list. With that said I would ask for a brake down of what that $8,900 is for, it sound a little high to me. All of that work could be done in one day with 2 people.  Also ask the landlord if you could get your own estimate, if he refuses then ask why. Most landlord will let you do what you want (with in the law) as long as you put it back the why you found it when you leave. If you do go with the landlords quote make sure that you get to keep everything that you are paying for.